# How to draw lines in WebGL, HTML5 or CSS3 for a tree algorithm?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

How do I draw lines of a specific color on a canvas using either WebGL, HTML5 or CSS3.

I am basically a beginner and starting on it with drawing a tree algorithm. I want to draw lines connecting the parent node to its child nodes. Could someone lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely need to use Javascript to draw lines on the canvas.  You might want to look at a library like [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) which provides an API to make drawing on the canvas a lot easier.

If you don't want to use a library, drawing lines on the canvas looks something like this:

```
var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myDrawing');
// Check the element is in the DOM and the browser supports canvas
if(drawingCanvas.getContext) {
    // Initaliase a 2-dimensional drawing context
    var ctx = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(5*14,5);
    ctx.lineTo(5*14,140);
    ctx.stroke()
}
```